# Take consideration of new java classes generated

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I want to transform a XML file into Java Classes in a Web Application. I have used the following code, which is working.

```
// Etape 1- generation d'un  schema à partir d'un fichier xml
File instanceFile=new File("produitxml.xml");//Fichier XML à transformer
final Inst2XsdOptions options = new Inst2XsdOptions();
options.setDesign(Inst2XsdOptions.DESIGN_RUSSIAN_DOLL);
final XmlObject[] xml = new XmlObject[] {XmlObject.Factory.parse(instanceFile)};
final SchemaDocument[] schemaDocs = Inst2Xsd.inst2xsd(xml, options);
//Generation du schema en specifiant le nom du fichier ou on va sauvgarder le schema
schemaDocs[0].save(new File("schema"), new XmlOptions().setSavePrettyPrint());

//Etape 2- generation de la classe Product à partir du schema XSD
SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
sc.forcePackageName("test6");//Specification du package du destination
// Specification du schema XSD
File schemaFile = new File("out3.xsd");
InputSource is = new InputSource(schemaFile.toURI().toString());
// Génération du classe java en spécifiant son emplacement
sc.parseSchema(is);
S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();
JCodeModel jCodeModel = model.generateCode(null, null);
jCodeModel.build(new File("schema"));
```

However, with this way of doing, I need to refresh the project. But what I want is an automatic refresh because I want to use this function in a web service (Rest API application) developed with Spring Boot.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "need to refresh the project". I don't get what maven has to do with a call on a method. Can you please elaborate with a high-level example?

Comment: You can add your generated classes to spcific classloader. For example look [here](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/05/tip-add-resources-dynamically-to-a-classloader.html)